# Qtile/14.04 - Battery monitor widget showing "Error"

Tags: battery

I have installed 14.04 on a HP Pavilion laptop, and have set up qtile as my WM. I went to install the widget.Battery() to display my battery stats, but instead it just says "Error".

I've installed apmd and verified that both apmd and apicd are running. Anyone have any thoughts on what I need to do to get the statistics to show up?

Edit: Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```
widget_defaults = dict(
    font='Terminus',
    fontsize=16,
    padding=3,
)
```

...

```
widget.Battery(
    energy_now_file='charge_now',
    energy_full_file='charge_full',
    power_now_file='current_now',
    **widget_defaults
),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while of searching, I found the answer in /sys/class/power_suppy/ the name of the battery on my laptop is "BAT1", yet the qtile configuration default is "BAT0". Once I updated my config to include "battery_name='BAT1',  it worked like a charm.